# Need help building a filter to edit the output of "image_send_to_editor"

Tags: images, filters

What I'm trying to do is edit the output of `image_send_to_editor` so that i can make the anchor that wraps around the image have a specific **class** & **rel**.

I plan to basically make each image that gets inserted into a post become fancybox capable without having to be in a gallery or using a plugin.

Heres what I have thus far but I need help filling in the blanks...

```
<?php
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'fancy_capable', 10, 7);
function fancy_capable($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $url, $size ) {
// not sure what to do here???
return "$html";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet here would be to use jQuery to grab any link that links to an image and tell it to use fanceybox.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[href$="jpg"], a[href$="png"], a[href$="jpeg"]').fancybox();
});
```

If you want this to work just for your post content areas use this:

```
$('.post-content a[href$="jpg"], .post-content  a[href$="png"], .post-content a[href$="jpeg"]').fancybox();
```

You will need to replace .post-content with whatever HTML parent element wraps the content area.

Comment: So this isnt possible through that filter then I take it?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but it's hard to test because you're dealing with PHP and Javascript actions happening all at once. You'll minus out the nightmare of trying to get this to work with this one line of jQuery. I've used it for years since it casts a wide net over the DOM to find any links appropriate for fancybox.

Comment: I thought that this filter takes place during "insertion of an image into a post" though, not when the page loads each time, no?

Comment: You are correct, but because JS events are happening (closing the iframe content, thickbox close, insert HTML into editor, etc...) there is no real place to output and debug what you're trying to do unless you add a Javascript tag in there and log stuff to the developer tools or firebug console.

Comment: Hmmm..ok. So is your JQuery script calling "all" jpg's, png's, and jpeg's though because that wont work for what Im trying to achieve, I only want to effect images inserted into posts.

Comment: Is there a way to target all images in a specific containing div without the anchor already having a specific ID similar to that method?

Comment: I'm actually not calling images. I'm calling all links with an href that contains an image. Technically, that's what Fancybox is for - to display image links inline.  I also  updated the code to show you how I target a specific part of the DOM.

Comment: Oh awesome! Apoligies, I only know how to hack away at jquery and the backend of WP right now...still need to get my game up in both areas a bit. I'll give this a go tomorrow and report back, sounds like it'll do just fine I was just kinda hell bent and keeping it all achievable through WPs backend but no matter. Thanks again for the help..

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: Worked great man, thank you for the simple solution! Never realized there was a CSS selector such as this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty easy... the `return $html;` is just going to return to the editor whatever you send to it... so you could do something like this:

```
<?php 
       add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'fancy_capable', 10, 7);
       function fancy_capable($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $url, $size ) {
           $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id); // Grab the current image URL
           $html = '<a href="' . $url .  '" class="fancybox" rel="your-rel"><img src="..." /></a>';
           return $html;
       }
?>
```

You can also just insert a shortcode (which may be more familiar to the user) in place of the HTML... and then have your shortcode do the work on the backend.

```
<?php 
       add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'fancy_capable', 10, 7);
       function fancy_capable($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $url, $size ) {
           $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id); // Grab the current image URL
           $html = '[image src="' . $url .  '" fancybox="true" /]';
           return $html;
       }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found some examples of using regular expressions to add some classes to the HTML. This works for me:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'add_class_to_image', 10, 8);
```

with the following function:

```
function add_class_to_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt='') {
    $classes_to_add = 'media-img';
    if (preg_match('/<a.? class=".?">/', $html))
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.? class=".?)(".\?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes_to_add . '$2', $html);
    else
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes_to_add . '">', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

Then, in my style.css file I styled the `a.media-img` selector.